# Авторизация php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nick']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    $nick = $_POST['nick']; 
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $nick = stripslashes($nick);
    $nick = htmlspecialchars($nick);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
    $nick = trim($nick);
    $password = trim($password);
    $password = md5($password);
if($nick == ""){
    echo "<div class='err'>Введите ник</div>";
}elseif($password == ""){
    echo "<div class='err'>Введите пароль</div>";
}else{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE nick='$nick' AND password='$password'",$db);
    if (empty($myrow['password']))
    {
    echo "<div class='err'>Введённый вами ник или пароль неверный</div>";
    }
    else {
    if ($myrow['password'] == $password) {
    $_SESSION['nick'] = $myrow['nick']; 
        echo "Вы успешно вошли на сайт! <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>";
        exit();
    }
    else {
    echo "<div class='err'>Введённый вами ник или пароль неверный</div>";
    }
}
}
}
?>

<div id="auth">
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<b>Ник:</b> <br><input class="text_input" type="text" name="nick"><br>
<b>Пароль:</b> <br><input class="text_input" type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input class="auth_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Играть">
</form>
</div>

<p class="reg"><a href="reg.php" title="Регистрация">» Регистрация</a></p>

<div class="footer">&copy; <?=date("Y");?></div>

<p></body>
</html></p>
```

Что здесь не так???

Comment: [поиск][1] в помощь.

Правильно оформи ответ.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&t=question

Comment: а в чем вопрос-то? наверное чтото не работает? какой результат?

Comment: Да тут видно что запрос в БД идет, а разбирать он его не разбирает т.к. нет этой строки в коде, но дальше он ее всячески использует, вот и ошибка - недописанный код!

Comment: да я не вчитывался в этот хаос))) да и мнение автора хочется что у него не получается :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, у тебя не хватает строки **$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);**

```
 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['nick']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) { 
        $nick = $_POST['nick']; 
        $password = $_POST['pass']; 
        $nick = stripslashes($nick); 
        $nick = htmlspecialchars($nick); 
        $password = stripslashes($password); 
        $password = htmlspecialchars($password); 
        $nick = trim($nick); 
        $password = trim($password); 
        $password = md5($password); 
        if($nick == ""){ 
            echo "<div class='err'>Введите ник</div>"; 
        }elseif($password == ""){ 
            echo "<div class='err'>Введите пароль</div>"; 
        }else{ 
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE nick='$nick' AND password='$password'",$db); 
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if (empty($myrow['password'])) { 
                echo "<div class='err'>Введённый вами ник или пароль неверный</div>"; 
            } else { 
                if ($myrow['password'] == $password) { 
                    $_SESSION['nick'] = $myrow['nick']; 
                    echo "Вы успешно вошли на сайт! <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>"; 
                    exit(); 
                } else { 
                    echo "<div class='err'>Введённый вами ник или пароль неверный</div>"; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } ?>
```

Comment: спасибо     3вцув